# How to get the correct Hits/sec graph using test data csv?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Whenever i am saving the test output in csv using jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false to reduce output file size i am able to get correct graph data for all graphs except Hits/sec where i am seeing only a single spike. Is there any property that i need to add so Hits/sec graph can process data correctly from the csv?

Answer (score 0):

In your .jmx script, you have to verify the options that are selected for '*Transactions per second*' graph generation.Here is an example that works for me without any issues (Jmeter version 5.3; you have to click configure button to display the list of options):
[image: Transactions per second graph setup]